# Ramsey Numbers for Integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, computational-number-theory, ramsey-theory

Erdos defined $f(n)$ to be the minimum $r$ such that there is an $r$-coloring of the positive integers less than $n$, wherein $n$ cannot be written as the sum of distinct monochromatic integers.  There are a number of papers on bounds for $f(n)$ by Erdos, Alon, Vu, Conlon and others.  I wonder if any specific values are known, and if for what n?  It seems an interesting computational challenge.  This is different from Schur numbers where all sums are forbidden, here only sums to $n$ are forbidden.

For example, the largest $n$ with $f(n) = 2$ seems to be $11$.  The integers $1$ to $10$ can be partitioned $\{1,3,4,5,9\}$ and $\{2,6,7,8,10\}$.

Comment: $n=(n-1)+1=(n-2)+2$ for every $n$.

Comment: By "distinct integers" do you mean "integers with distinct colours"?

Comment: If you want to avoid all monochromatic solutions to $x+y=z$ in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, your question is about what are known as Schur numbers which allow $x=y$ ([OEIS A045652](https://oeis.org/A045652)) or weak Schur numbers which require $x \ne y$ ([OEIS A072842](https://oeis.org/A072842)).  Results about 5 colors were done recently using SAT solvers and *peta*bytes of computations.

Comment: Yes, I left out the key word 'monochromatic'.  Note that this not the same as Schur numbers.